# How to verify that my Windows 10 licence is associated with my Hotmail/Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

From what I've read, I Windows 10 license is associated with my Windows (Hotmail) account. This means I can change some/most/all hardware and not lose the license.

I have read that if I don't have the Hotmail/Outlook account then it won't associate the license. This isn't a problem because I have a Hotmail account. When I log into Windows, I login using that account (and I assume the fact it syncs with One Drive is verification of this).

What I can't tell is how to verify that the license is associated correctly. What I'm concerned about is changing Hardware and it turns out I had not performed a vital procedure to make the association/registration.

How do I tell if my Windows / Hotmail account has an associated Windows 10 license?

Comment: "From what I've read, I Windows 10 license is associated with my Windows (Hotmail) account." - Only if you are running Version 1607+ and only if you connect your local account to a Microsoft Account, and only if you turn this feature on.  This feature is seperate from syncing your settings by the way.

Comment: "What I can't tell is how to verify that the license is associated correctly." - Don't worry about it.  No matter what your license is handled through a digital entitlement system, since you upgraded from Windows 7, connecting your license to your Microsoft Account is primarly for those who have a retail license.

Comment: @Ramhound and what about those of us that DO have a retail license...?

Comment: @Ramhound  - "While you can connect your license to your account, how you do that, is exactly the same on Version 1607"  - this is what the OP wants to know how to do, and verify that it is done, so that they can change their hardware as much as they like (assuming they have a retail license).

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 7 retail licenses were upgraded to Windows 10 retail licenses during the 1 year free upgrade period for those of us that accepted the offer. There was initially some confusion about this, but MS released a statement confirming it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50000/discussion-between-beowulfnode42-and-ramhound).

Comment: is the question answered or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do [those steps](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/15/link-microsoft-account-windows-10-license/):

- Use the keyboard shortcut Windows-I to open the Settings application.
- Select Update & Security.
- Select Activation

[image]

Here you see the current status. If the account has no licence you can click on `Add an account`, enter your account data and the account gets the license added.

You can see this in the next step in the same dialog:

[image]

> Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft
>   account.

Comment: You may also find the page https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/20527/windows-10-activation-troubleshooter useful. Also try logging in to your MS account and look to see if your device is listed there.